# Can ping specific website but cannot browse it

Tags: networking, dns, browser, ping

I wanted to download the new version of Eclipse yesterday and when I went to the website www.eclipse.org I got the following error:

```
This site can’t be reached

eclipse.org took too long to respond.

Try:
    Checking the connection
    Checking the proxy and the firewall
    Running Network Diagnostics

ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

I can ping the website, but I cannot access it. This happens with all wired and wireless devices in my house. I can browse other websites without any issues. I was able to access the website from my university, so I know that the problem is not with the eclipse website. I unplugged my FIOS router and it did not change anything. No settings have been changed in the recent past that I know of. Again, this is the only website that has any issues. Does anybody have an idea what the problem might be?

Comment: The website may have special credentials only allowable from the university. On the other hand, sometimes there is a difference with http and https. If there is use of https, try taking the 's' off and use only the http; or visa versa.

Comment: I have no problems accessing `www.eclipse.org` nor problems with `http://eclipse.org`. Try both

Comment: @ejbytes eclipse.org is very much a publicly-accessible website. There's some merit in trying both HTTPS and non-HTTPS. Miguel, if you can, try a `tcping` on ports 80 and 443.

Comment: yeah i noticed that after I went to the site. I've downloaded eclipse from there many times when I attended UC. See my other msg.

Comment: I tried `www.eclipse.org`, `http://eclipse.org`, and `https://eclipse.org` with the same results. I ran `tcping www.eclipse.org 80` and got `www.eclipse.org port 80 open.` I then ran `tcping www.eclipse.org 443` and got `www.eclipse.org port 443 closed.` What does that mean?

Comment: Another thing I remembered having problems with my connection or intermittent connectivity was my IP configuration with my router and my DNS. I had problems with "Obtain Automatically" and "Obtain DNS Automatically". So I use static IP and static DNS. Some people throw serious TANTRUMS when I offer the solution of using Google's DNS. But that's what I did and my internet is much better now. I'm not a Networking expert, but my DNS hasn't had a problem since. Just an FYI.

Comment: Also sometimes it's a good idea to "power cycle" your router. Unplug it, plug it back in. Also, are you Cat connected or wifi?

Comment: I already power cycled my router and it did not change anything. I tried both wifi and ethernet connections. I got that `www.eclipse.org port 443 closed.` when running tcping.

Comment: What do you need a specific port to be open for if you are just visiting the website? Are you FTP'ing something?

Comment: My 443 port is open. However, I opened it manually in my router for using the Mozilla FTP.

Comment: Some sites "reject" or block ping requests, so remember that. Because being open to ping request is also open to Hackers and other malicious behavior. So a ping might fail on many websites. I don't know if there are any sites that reject public IP's once a ping is requested though.

Comment: I do not want to transfer anything using FTP. I just want to visit the website using my browsers. @bob suggested to use `tcping` to check if those ports were open or not for that website. After doing so, 443 was closed on for that specific website.